# Text-Classification RNN - LSTM - Error checking target

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, text-classification, recurrent-neural-network

i'm developing a LSTM - RNN text classification with Keras
This is my Code.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import keras
import sklearn
import gensim
import random
import scipy
from keras.preprocessing import text
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense , Dropout , Activation  , Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers import Embedding , LSTM
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC , SVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec , TaggedDocument

# size of the word embeddings
embeddings_dim = 300

# maximum number of words to consider in the representations
max_features = 30000

# maximum length of a sentence
max_sent_len = 50

# percentage of the data used for model training
percent = 0.75

# number of classes
num_classes = 2

print ("")
print ("Reading pre-trained word embeddings...")
embeddings = dict( )
embeddings = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz" , binary=True) 

print ("Reading text data for classification and building representations...")
data = [ ( row["sentence"] , row["label"]  ) for row in csv.DictReader(open("test-data.txt"), delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE) ]
random.shuffle( data )
train_size = int(len(data) * percent)
train_texts = [ txt.lower() for ( txt, label ) in data[0:train_size] ]
test_texts = [ txt.lower() for ( txt, label ) in data[train_size:-1] ]
train_labels = [ label for ( txt , label ) in data[0:train_size] ]
test_labels = [ label for ( txt , label ) in data[train_size:-1] ]
num_classes = len( set( train_labels + test_labels ) )
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n', lower=True, split=" ")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_texts)
train_sequences = sequence.pad_sequences( tokenizer.texts_to_sequences( train_texts ) , maxlen=max_sent_len )
test_sequences = sequence.pad_sequences( tokenizer.texts_to_sequences( test_texts ) , maxlen=max_sent_len )
train_matrix = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix( train_texts )
test_matrix = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix( test_texts )
embedding_weights = np.zeros( ( max_features , embeddings_dim ) )
for word,index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
  if index < max_features:
    try: embedding_weights[index,:] = embeddings[word]
    except: embedding_weights[index,:] = np.random.rand( 1 , embeddings_dim )
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder( )
le.fit( train_labels + test_labels )
train_labels = le.transform( train_labels )
test_labels = le.transform( test_labels )
print("Classes that are considered in the problem : " + repr( le.classes_ ))


print("-----WEIGHTS-----")
print(embedding_weights.shape)

print ("Method = Stack of two LSTMs")
np.random.seed(0)
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(max_features, embeddings_dim, input_length=max_sent_len, mask_zero=True, weights=[embedding_weights] ))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=embeddings_dim , activation='sigmoid', inner_activation='hard_sigmoid', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(activation="sigmoid", units=embeddings_dim, recurrent_activation="hard_sigmoid", return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', class_mode='binary')
else: model.compile(Adam(lr=0.04),'categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()


model.fit(train_sequences, train_labels , epochs=30, batch_size=32)
```

My model is this:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 50, 300)           9000000   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 50, 300)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 50, 300)           721200    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 50, 300)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 50, 300)           721200    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 50, 300)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 50, 1)             301       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 50, 1)             0         
=================================================================
Total params: 10,442,701
Trainable params: 10,442,701
Non-trainable params: 0
```

My error is:
Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (750, 1)

I try to reshape all my array, but i not found the solution.
Can someone help me??? thank you :D
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What is the shape of `train_sequences` and `train_labels`?

Comment: (750,50) e (750,)

Answer (score 0):

You need to one hot encode your labels. You can use Keras `to_categorical` method to convert your label encoded integers.

Comment: thank's, but i've already an error: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (750, 2). I use train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes)
test_labels =  to_categorical(test_labels, num_classes)..can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

finally, my model is

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(max_features, embeddings_dim, input_length=max_sent_len, mask_zero=True, weights=[embedding_weights] ))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=embeddings_dim , activation='sigmoid', inner_activation='hard_sigmoid', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(activation='sigmoid', units=embeddings_dim, recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

adam=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.04)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

But accuracy is very bad!!! :(